# Iterative deepening with a time limit

Tags: chess, alpha-beta-pruning, iterative-deepening

I'm working on implementing iterative deepening with principal variation for alpha-beta search for a computer chess program, and I was hoping to include a time limit for the search. I was wondering about the consequences of the time limit being reached in the middle of, say, a search at a depth of 5. If this incomplete search has found a new principal variation, would that be guaranteed to be at least as good as the principal variation found by the complete search at a depth of 4? Otherwise, it seems like I should throw out anything found by the incomplete search at a depth of 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you stop in the middle of an iteration you can use the best move found so far backed up to the root on that iteration. It's not *guaranteed* to be at least as good as the best move found by the previous iteration but it *is* ordered above it by the current iteration. The *best* scoring move will be missed on the current iteration only if it's ordered below the stopping move.